# Issue showing uploaded file name on Button click? fiddle provided

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, popup

I have a button and on click of that it opens a popup with `Upload File control` with a button `Add` side to it  .

Well what i am trying to do is bit tricky and i hope someone can show some way to get through this .

**scenario :** i am facing difficulty when i choose a file using upload control i get the file name with extension . On my `next step` when i click on `Add` i need the uploaded file name to `come below` likely no matter what how many files i upload when i click on Add those file names should show below in form of link .

**Working fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/SnPdE/685/

Any workaround is extremely helpful

Comment: have a look at http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: well i been trying to be use mostly knockout if things are inevitable i should try jquery . any suggestion on given fiddle is appreciated

Comment: In order to upload the files you will need to use ajax which is why you will need jquery. The problem with uploading files with ajax is it's only available in modern browsers such as IE 10+, Chrome, Firefox Safari. This is why you need to use something like the jquery file upload plugin. It uses an iframe in older browsers to upload the files asynchronously.

Comment: @WayneEllery i agree with you and i will look into your suggestion . coming to my post pivotal point , i looking for something different i.e once after uploading when i click on add button how can i show the uploaded file below . please check the attached image and fiddle . cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Well finally done it myself with some googling around stack-overflow .

My Updated `fiddle` contains all code : http://jsfiddle.net/LhRuC/3/

wayne & huocp thank you for you valuable time and suggestions